# Assigning multiple classes to a tag using PHPTAL

Tags: php, templates, template-tal, phptal

I have an array of data I want to output as a UL using PHPTAL (easy) with class attributes supplied by the array (easy), a class attribute for first and for the last element (easy)... all at the same time (hard).

Ie. I want to combine:

```
<ul tal:repeat="item items">
    <li class="${item/class}">${item/text}</li>
</ul>
```

with this

```
<ul tal:repeat="item items">
    <li tal:attributes="class repeat/item/first 'first'">${item/text}</li>
</ul>
```

and this

```
<ul tal:repeat="item items">
    <li tal:attributes="class repeat/item/last 'last'">${item/text}</li>
</ul>
```

This is purely presentational stuff, so I'd rather do it purely in PHPTAL. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Link to the documentation : http://phptal.org/manual/en/split/

Comment: @UgoMéda: been there, read that, still no wiser. Maybe you could link to a relevant section, e.g. http://phptal.org/manual/en/split/tal-attributes.html - which doesn't answer the question BTW.

Comment: I was just adding this for easy access for helpers. Can't help you more than that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no pure TALES for this.

```
<li tal:attributes="class php:repeat.item.last ? 'last' 
                          : (repeat.item.first ? 'first' : NULL)">
```

Comment: Aha! Nested ifs - man, haven't thought of them for ages. Should work though, so many thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old thread, but because no one mentioned it: an 'cleaner' way is probably through a custom modifier. (http://phptal.org/manual/en/split/custom-modifiers.html). Then you could have:

```
<li tal:attributes="class css-ordinal:repeat.item">
```

and as a benefit, you could reuse that in other elements, as it seems a pretty general idiom.